# R - Number of occurrences of a string in a column of excel

Tags: r, stringr

I'm using the `stringr`library to count the number of occurrences of an array of strings in a column in excel.

```
string.arr =  c(
    "I can't handle this.",
    "I shouldn't be this stressed out.",
    ... more possible strings ...
)
```

Sample data:

```
1 col_name

2 “I’m never going to succeed.”,“The professor will be disappointed in me.”,“Other students won’t want to work with me.”,“I shouldn't be this stressed out.",“Other people can handle this situation - what's wrong with me?"
3 “Everyone will think I am dumb.”,“People will make jokes about me if I get the wrong answer.”,“I shouldn't be this stressed out.",“Other people can handle this situation - what's wrong with me?"
4 ... more such rows ...
```

As you can see from the Sample data, there are two kinds of apostrophes used `'` and `’`. However, in R, I'm only able to use `'` while creating the `string.arr`. Consequently, the code (below) is not counting the strings which have `’` in them.

```
for (string in string.arr) {
 sum(str_count(deidentified_data_text_df$col_name, string), na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

It's not feasible to modify the data. Can I solve this in the code such that both `'` and `’` in the data are detected by `'` in the code.

I'm open to using any other package in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

If `string.arr` contains what is essentially a list of key words (or sentences) that you want to match in larger text and the problem is that that larger text may contain two kinds of apostrophes, then you might simply replace all apostrophes in `string.arr` by a regex alternation group:

```
string.arr <- gsub("’|'", "(’|')", string.arr)
```

Result:

```
string.arr
[1] "I can(’|')t handle this."              
[2] "They won(’|')t handle this"            
[3] "I shouldn(’|')t be this stressed out."
[4] "no apostrophe"
```

Data:

```
string.arr =  c(
  "I can’t handle this.",                          # bent apostrophe
  "They won't handle this",                        # straight apostrophe
  "I shouldn't be this stressed out.",             # straight apostrophe
  "no apostrophe"                                  # no apostrophe
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry that my question wasn't clearer. string.arr is not the sample data. string.arr is the array of strings that I need to match from the sample data. I have updated the code. I need the apostrophes to be part of the string and not separate.

Comment: I think it will be much easier to help you if you post some **reproducible data** as part o the question (what you call `Sample data` is not one-to-one reproducible. Overall, it further seems that the question is lacking in clarity.